Apple RealityKit: How to draw a concave polygon using ModelEntity?
Sometimes generate concave using MeshResource are not correct.
Here's a demo image:

This is my code:
public func polygon(points: [simd_float3], name: String, color: UIColor) -> ModelEntity? {
     
    let counts: [UInt8] = [UInt8(points.count)]
    var indices: [UInt32] = []
            
    for index in 0..<points.count {
    indices.append(UInt32(index))}
        
    primitivesType = .polygons(counts, indices)
   
    var meshDescriptor = MeshDescriptor()
    meshDescriptor.positions = .init(positions)
    meshDescriptor.primitives = primitivesType
    let polygon = try! MeshResource.generate(from: [meshDescriptor])
    let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: polygon, materials: [unlitmaterial_])
    entity.name = name
   
    return entity
}

have any way to improve this draw func
    MeshResource.generate
    var meshDescriptor = MeshDescriptor()
    meshDescriptor.positions = .init(positions)
    meshDescriptor.primitives = primitivesType
    let polygon = try! MeshResource.generate(from: [meshDescriptor])
    let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: polygon, materials: [unlitmaterial_])

